# I am trying to apply a defined function to a grouped pandas grouped dataframe and output the results to a csv

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

I have a defined function that requires a list, and the function outputs one value for every item in the list. I need to group by industry code (SIC), and apply the function within industry (so only industry 1 firms are grouped together for the defined calculation).
example:

```
1       50
1       40
2       100
2       110
```

I do the following code:

```
dr=pd.read_csv("sample.csv", usecols=columns)
d1=dr.groupby('SIC')['value'].apply(list)
for groups in d1
    a=my_function(groups)
    b=pd.DataFrame(A)
    b.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

I expected to get an output file with the function values for all 4 rows (lets say I want the difference between that row and the average. row 1 should be `50-(avg(50+40))` which equals 5.

Instead, I get a csv file with only the last group's values. It seems like I should make a new CSV file for each group, but by doing the `apply(list)` I cant figure out how to identify each group.
Edit: I modified the functionality as described in the comment below to output only one file.

Comment: "make a new CSV file for each group" - `for i, groups in enumerate(d1): # your code...; b.to_csv(f'output{i}.csv', index=False)`

Comment: @ForceBru thank you. This worked. I ended up finding a way to output all results to the same csv, by doing a list and using my ```for groups in d1``` section to extend that list, then output the entire list to one file. Thank you for the assistance.